# Meaning of “multiple entries”

Tags: meaning

What does the term “multiple entries” really mean in this text?

> Your journal needs to be at least 5 pages, with multiple **entries**.  Watch your spelling and grammar.

Does it mean multiple paragraphs? I’m confused.

Comment: In the practice of keeping a diary or journal, an entry is, roughly speaking, a line (or a couple of lines) that's treated as a separate textual entity. So, *multiple entries* then means *a number of such entities*.

Answer (score 3):

The key here is understanding how a journal works.

If I was keeping a journal as I took a two-week hike, I would probably write details several times over the two weeks. I would write at least once every couple days, but I might even write daily, or even more than once on a particular day.

An ***entry*** in a journal is one session where I am writing something in the journal.

So, on the evening of the first day, I might write something like:

> Set up camp on a nice ridge with a scenic overlook. Glad I got everything set up in time to watch the sunset. It was gorgeous! Looking forward to a good night's rest after a long day.

Then, the next morning, I might write again:

> Sure was a chilly night! Good thing I packed the heavy sleeping bag instead of the light one. Planning to break camp after a light breakfast and then get moving.

Those would be two ***entries*** in my journal.

Whoever is asking you to write your journal is saying that you can't write one entry that's five pages long; rather, your five pages must be comprised of multiple entries.

Technically, two entries would qualify as "multiple," but I'm guessing that whoever will be reading your journal would be more likely to want to see at least five or ten entries, and not merely two or three, depending on how long you are expected to be journaling.

Answer (score 0):

J.R.'s answer is probably correct; however it's not clear from the context what kind of journal OP is talking about.  A general journal might be a daily recording of one's thoughts, observations, and feelings, but there are other more specific uses.

One of these is the [*accounting journal*](https://www.accountingcoach.com/blog/what-is-a-journal):

> In accounting and bookkeeping, a journal is a record of financial transactions in order by date. A journal is often defined as the book of original entry. The definition was more appropriate when transactions were written in a journal prior to manually posting them to the accounts in the general ledger or subsidiary ledger. Manual systems usually had a variety of journals such as a sales journal, purchases journal, cash receipts journal, cash disbursements journal, and a general journal.

In this case "multiple entries" would mean "multiple records of financial transactions", each of which would be recorded *on a separate line*.  Naturally, these days there is software for this, but who knows what the teacher/professor might require.

Additionally there are *engineering/scientific* journals, in which each *entry* should be recorded in a specific way that is usually taught to students early on.